# Vue Js running code when Modal has been oepend

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a link that has an ID, and I am trying to load data in to my form once the bootstrap is open (because the id can be different than the one when the page loads) How can I only run my method, once the modal has been opened?

I want to run the setData method every time the modal is oepened via a link

```
<template>
    <div>
       <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Edit Job</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    export default
    {
        // I want to run this every time the modal is opened
        setData: function()
        {
            axios.get('/jobs/my-job/' + this.id)
            .then(response => {
                this.name = response.data.name
                this.summary = response.data.summary
                this.salarytype = response.data.salary_type
                this.salaryfrom = response.data.salary_from
                this.salaryto = response.data.salary_to
                this.location = response.data.location
                this.contactemail = response.data.contact
                this.contactphone = response.data.phone
            })
        },
</script>
```

My html file has the called component which is opened via a link:

```
<a data-id='{$job->id}' onclick='getID({$job->id})' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#editJob'>


<div id="app">
    <div id="editJob" class="modal fade in" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content" id="edit-job">
                <edit-job :id="id"></edit-job>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> 
</div>
```

Set data is in my edit-job component:

```
Vue.component('edit-job', require('./pages/jobs/edit-job.vue'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To perform my task, I didn't need to check if the modal opened. On the initial page load my prop Id is set to null. So I created a watcher for when my ID changes to run my method:

```
    watch: {
        id: function(newid){
            this.setData()      
        }
    },
```

I will  leave this answer open if any one wants to add to the discussion of better ways etc.